# (n-1) derivative in residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

$$
\int _0^{+\infty }\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^n}
$$

This integral has been addressed for $n = 2$, let's attempt to solve it for all $n$.

The residue theorem has led me to:

$$
\frac{2\pi i}{\left(n-1\right)!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{\:n-1}}{\mathrm{d}z^{\:n-1}}\frac{1}{\left(z + \mathrm{i}a\right)^{\,n}}
$$

I could use some help with that derivative, thank you.

Comment: Did you make an attempt to calculate the derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To Compute Your Derivative**

Apply $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}(z+ia)^k=k(z+ia)^{k-1}$, iteratively, $n-1$ times ($k=-n$ to $k=-2n+2$): 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{(n-1)!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n-1}}{\mathrm{d}z^{n-1}} (z+ia)^{-n}
&=(-1)^{n-1}\frac1{(n-1)!}n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n-2)(z+ia)^{-2n+1}\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}(z+ia)^{-2n+1}
\end{align}
$$
Now plug in $z=ia$.

---

**A Different Approach**

Assume $a\gt0$. Using the binomial theorem, we can compute the residue at $z=ia$:
$$
\begin{align}
\left[(z-ia)^{-1}\right]\frac1{(z-ia)^n(z+ia)^n}
&=\left[(z-ia)^{-1}\right](z-ia)^{-n}{\underbrace{(z-ia+2ia)}_{z+ia}}^{-n}\tag1\\
&=\left[(z-ia)^{n-1}\right](z-ia+2ia)^{-n}\tag2\\[6pt]
&=(2ia)^{-n}\left[(z-ia)^{n-1}\right]\left(1+\frac{z-ia}{2ia}\right)^{-n}\tag3\\[3pt]
&=(2ia)^{-n}\binom{-n}{n-1}(2ia)^{1-n}\tag4\\
&=(2ia)^{1-2n}(-1)^{n-1}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\tag5\\
&=-i\frac1{(2a)^{2n-1}}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: write $z+ia=z-ia+2ia$
$(2)$: $\left[(z-ia)^{-1}\right](z-ia)^{-n}f(z)=\left[(z-ia)^{n-1}\right]f(z)$
$(3)$: pull $(2ia)^{-n}$ out front
$(4)$: apply the ["coefficient of" operator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients) to the binomial expansion
$(5)$: compute the negative binomial coefficient
$(6)$: collect terms

Since the integrand is even, we take half the integral over the whole real line, which is $\pi i$ times the residue at $z=ia$.
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^n}=\frac{\pi}{(2a)^{2n-1}}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}
$$

Comment: I don't get the expression you're starting from, can you explain how the residue formula leads to it? f.e I don't see the $\frac{1}{\left(n-1\right)!}$ or the derivative

Comment: The residue at $z=ia$ is the coefficient of $(z-ia)^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion around $z=ia$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laurent series, any steps you had to take to figure it out or you could just write the function times the -1 coefficient?

Comment: You know that you are looking for the coefficient of the $(z-ia)^{-1}$ term, right?

Comment: Hi, what happens if $a<0$? Then $-ia$ is our residue and we get $\left(-2ia\right)^{-2n+1}$ in the end instead, if we pull $i$ out is it again $-i$?

Comment: The integrand is even in $a$, so the integral for $a\lt0$ is the same as for $a\gt0$. The residue changes sign, but the direction of the contour changes from counter-clockwise (circling the upper half plane) to clockwise (circling the lower half plane), so the integral comes out the same.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for making that clear.

Comment: One last thing, can you clarify the binomial coefficient in the first approach?

Comment: @Velyth: $\binom{2n-2}{n-1}=\frac{\overbrace{(2n-2)(2n-3)\cdots n}^{n-1\text{ terms}}}{(n-1)!}$

Answer (score 2):

I would start by writing the following:

$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \frac{1}{(z+ia)^n} = \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} (z+ia)^{-n} $$

Then each derivative uses the fact that $\frac{d}{dz}(u^\alpha ) = \alpha u^{\alpha-1} \frac{d}{dz}(u) $, and here $u = z+ia \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dz}u = 1$.

I think with this you can solve it, if I didn't miss anything.

Comment: You still have to apply the derivative n-1 times, though, beware

Comment: He means that 

$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}$$

of a function means to take the derivative $n-1$ times. The superscripts here indicate iteration, not raising the derivative to a power (since, after all, $d/dz$ is an operator).

Comment: I found this: $\frac{d^{\:k}}{dz^{\:k}}\left(z^n\right)=\frac{n!}{\left(n-k\right)!}z^{n-k}$ can I use it with $k = n-1$ and $n = -n$ ?

Comment: Nearly:  you should take care with negative factorials, if I were you I would take the minus sign out of the expression and write it: $\frac{d^k}{dz^k}(z^{-n}) = \frac{(-1)^k (n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!} z^{-(n+k)}$